# How to redirect users if there is no Internet connection in Ionic framework?

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to redirect users to a different page when they're not connected to the Internet.

My only question is why this is working:

```
if (window.Connection) {
    if(navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
        alert("Please connect to internet");
    }
}
```

and this is not

```
if (window.Connection) {
    if(navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
        $scope.state.go('offline');  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using `$state` the wrong way. Instead of this:

```
$scope.state.go('offline');
```

You should **do it like this**:

```
$state.go('offline');
```

Remember to inject `$state` in your controller. More information about $state from [official docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state).

By *Remember to inject $state in your controller* I'm referring, for example, to this:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $state) {
    $scope.changeState = function () {
        $state.go('someplaceNice');
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answer... i realised this minutes before your post.